# Including a custom js file on rails_admin dashboard

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets, rails-admin

I am trying to include a custom js for a custom field that depends on a google maps control, I don't want to mix html and js on a partial file, however, up to now, it appears to be the way to go.

I have checked on the wiki and the only reference about including a custom js is [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Theming-and-customization) but it doesn't work.

I only want to be able to organize my javascripts as usual (at *assets/javascripts/*) and be able to interact with my **rails_admin** form views. Anyone has any idea on how this should be handled?

Answer (score 1):

To restate: It sounds like you are trying to keep javascript code out of view (html/erb) files.

I can recommend one way you may wish to try.

If you look at the assets/javascript directory you can see the generated javascript files that are created per controller when you are scaffolding a resource.

These files are great for keeping all the code related to the controller context in.  there is another file named application.js which is great to keep global javascript routines in.

If you put tags/fields on the elements which you wish to select to bind a javascript method to you are able to keep the methods focused on finding and binding fields sharing the tag.

example:

field you wish to interact with:
Blah

your_controller_name.js:

using jquery you should be able to select the span by the data tag ( you could stored extra infor.  you can then also bind methods to the span.

$("span[data-interesting='hi there']").click(function() { console.log('someone clicked the span'); })

You could use a selector that is more general and do something useful to all the matching items.

Good luck!
James.

Comment: Thanks James. I already can do that on views from controllers outside the rails_admin scope, by the simply clean rails-way, however there must be a trick to make that clean rails-way js insertion work on rails_admin.